# Can I extend my stay for more than 16 days in Germany if my visa indicate duration of stay 16 days?

Tags: visas, germany, visa-extensions

I applied for a short term visa to visit family in Germany and my visa is indicating duration of stay is 16 days. My question is - can I stay longer than the 16 days the visa is indicating?

Comment: Well, obviously you can't legally stay longer than your visa allows. To get better answers about extending it, I suggest you edit the question by adding your nationality and more details about the visa, if possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Travel.SE. Please add more information about your situation into the question, otherwise this post will be closed as non-constructive.

Comment: I doubt the nationality makes a difference,  but any information  you can provide would be useful.

Comment: By the way, You cannot stay longer than what it says in your passport. However, once you're in the country there's a chance that the embassy can grant temporary visa on your passport. My friend has done that, but it depends on your reason as well.